# how to double values alphabet to numbers?

Tags: java, double, type-conversion

Add so many values and stored it as double value..

Its Value is `3.2179465E7`

But its Actual value is `32 179 465.00`

How I convert `32 179 465.00` from `3.2179465E7`

Comment: Do you want to convert it from a `String` to a `double`?

Comment: You know that `32179465` is exactly the same as `3.2179465E7`?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Agreed, but we don't know if it's coming in as a `String`. Could be reading from a text file for all we know, in which case there is only "3.2179465E7" as text.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind yes I know ,calculate so many values and finding this result as answer

Comment: Thank You Every one I solve my Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your value in scientific notation is a `String`, you can do this:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble("3.2179465E7");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in exponential format. Use `BigDecimal.valueOf()` to convert the `Double` value to BigDecimal.

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(yourEponantialValueVariable).toPlainString());
```

Comment: Why BigDecimal instead of just printing the double?

Comment: But it cant Display '.oo'